# Identifying a $\Delta$ complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am doing some self study and am having trouble with the following.  I want to say the answer is a cone, but I do not think that this is correct.  Help will be apreciated.

What familiar space is the quotient $\Delta$ complex of a 2 simplex $[v_0
, v_1
, v_2
]$ obtained
by identifying the edges $[v_0
, v_1
]$ and $[v_1
, v_2
]$, preserving the ordering of vertices?

Comment: +1 This is an excellent question, but it has nothing to do with homology.

Answer (score 10):

You get a cone if you identify the edges $[v_0, v_1]$ and $[v_1, v_2]$ *reversing* the ordering of the vertices (because you identify $v_0$ with $v_2$ and $v_1$ with $v_1$ when you do this).

To preserve the orientation, you need to make a "twist" to identify $v_0$ with $v_1$ and $v_1$ with $v_2$. This gives a Möbius band.

You can see more details (and pictures) [here](http://tarunchitra.com/papers/6510/hw6.pdf).

Comment: A Möbius band from a triangle: amazing!

Comment: It is strange for me to convince a Möbius band can be get from a triangle, simply because if I have a Möbius band and then, let a vertical line retracts to a point, WHY CAN'T I twist it back at that point?